# Angular directive for making elements ng-clickable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a reusable directive that generates a PDF report from a given object.

**Javascript:**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('DemoCtrl', [function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { test: 'testing!' }
}])

.directive('pdfMake', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<a ng-click="generatePdf(data)">generate PDF</a>',
    link: function($scope) {

      $scope.generatePdf = function(data) {
        alert(data)
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

**Template:**

```html
<button pdf-make data="data">Export Source</button>
```

or better yet...

```
<button pdf-make="data">Export Source</button>
```

The only problem is that I need to reuse the directive on different elements like `<button>`, `<span>`, or dropdown `<li>`'s.

I know I'm approaching it wrong because I specified a template when I don't want to replace the button text. I just need it to process the given data on click. I couldn't find any examples similar to what I'm trying to do. Is this possible with an isolated scope? Thanks.

**Update:**
Based on @chandings answer I updated my plunk the plunk and using `element.bind('click')` does the charm:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CkgCL1IM095PDSdd3zTS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need transclude. also there was problems with the way you had defined your controller.

it should either be

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('DemoCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { test: 'testing!' }
}])
```

or

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = { test: 'testing!' }
})
```

and here is a fork of your plunker link with my edits to make it working.

Hope this is what you want.
http://plnkr.co/edit/JmXEMFsZezha2N0rScko?p=preview

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to bind the click with element. Now I don't need to specify a template that will override my button text. By the way your code seems to work whether or not I insert a transclude. One last question, do you know of a way I can write it out `<div pdf-make="data">` rather than specifying `data=""` as a separate parameter? Thanks again.

Comment: update your scope to scope:{pdfMake:"="} and it should do the trick.
updated plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/JmXEMFsZezha2N0rScko?p=preview